# Angularjs hide or remove an item then replace it with the next available item on the list

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

in Angularjs if I have a list of elements
in it it has a array with an item called available
using ng-if or ng-show I would like to show 3 elements at a time
if one element have 0 items available then remove that one from the list and add the next, but I have an issue where the next element doesn't takes the place of the hidden or removed item unless I up the limitTo up to 4
any ideas? suggestions? do I use filter

here is my angular file

```
    (function(){
var app = angular.module("moxierevere",['ngCart']);

app.controller("ItemsController", function(){
    this.items = allItems;

});
var allItems = [
{
    id:0,
    name: "item1",
    image: "images/br.JPG" ,
    price: 2.00,
    available: 5,
    size: "S , M, L"
},
{
    id:1,
    name: "item2",
    image: "images/avacados.JPG" ,
    price: 5.00,
    available: 5,
    size: "S , M, L"
},
{
    id:2,
    name: "item3",
    image: "images/chicha.JPG" ,
    price: 2.00,
    available: 0,
    size: "S , M, L"
},
{
    id:3,
    name: "item4",
    image: "images/lomo.JPG" ,
    price: 6.00,
    available: true,
    size: "S , M, L"
},
{
    id:4,
    name: "item5",
    image: "images/satuna.JPG" ,
    price: 2.00,
    available: 5,
    size: "S , M, L"
}
];
})();
```

and here is my html

```
<body ng-app="moxierevere">
<div ng-controller="ItemsController as item">

    <div ng-repeat="all in item.items | limitTo:4" class="allItems" ng-if="all.available > 0">
    <ul>
        <li class="white ">{{all.name}}</li>
        <img ng-src="{{all.image}}" width="120px" height="120px" />
        <li class="white ">{{all.price|currency}}</li>
        <li class="white">{{all.size}}</li>
        <li><button>Add to Cart</button></li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    </div>
```

here is jsfiddle of it
http://jsfiddle.net/wayko/vp32u0yd/

Thank you so much for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the use of the `limitTo` filter. This filter is evaluated on your list of items prior to the ngRepeat directive receiving the list. The result is that the directive only operates on the first four items in your list.

Probably the cleanest solution would be to create a filter like `limitTo` that performs both the filtering and limitation functions.

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/vp32u0yd/3/

Edit: another approach (thanks to HankScorpio for making me think of this) is to use the `filter` filter combined with a predicate function.

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/vp32u0yd/6/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the order of events. First it's limiting `item.items`, and then processing ngIf on each item in that limited list.
The easiest way is probably just to add a filter that you can insert before `limitTo`

```
myModule.filter('availableItems', function() {
  return function(items) {
    return items.filter(function(item){
        return item.available > 0;
    });
  };
});
```

-

```
<div ng-repeat="all in item.items | availableItems | limitTo:4" class="allItems">...</div>
```

Comment: I don't believe this is going to work as written. The `item` argument to the filter will be the entire array, not a single item.